# Effects of Filter Topology on transfer function

Tags: filter, transfer-function

Does the transfer function of a filter change if I change its topology keeping the cutoff frequency and the order same?

Answer (score 3):

No - the transfer function of a filter does not depend on the selected topology. However, this applies to IDEAL conditions only. That means: Ideal properties of the active elements as well as for all passive parts (no tolerances).

If these requirements of ideality are not "sufficiently" fulfilled ("sufficiently" means: with acceptable error) different topologies will exhibit different deviations from the desired transfer function. This is the most important criterion for selecting one of the various topologies for a certain application. As an example, the well-known Sallen-Key topology is less sensitive to the opamps finite open-loop gain values (frequency dependent gain) but pretty sensitive to parts tolerances. In this respect, the so called multi-feedback topology (MFB) has opposite properties.

To select a suitable topology for a specific application is a rather challenging task for an engineer bacause he has to take into account technical as well as economical aspects.

In short: Under ideal conditions all topologies give the same filter behaviour - however, because nothing is ideal, it is important to select the "proper" method for realizing the filter. In particular, this applies to higher-order filters because, in these cases, we have to select between two principles: Series connection of active second-order stages or active realzation of passive RLC structures (Keywords: Leap frog, active L-simulation, FDNR technique).

**EDIT/UPDATE:** For better explaining the influence of non-ideal opamp data on filter performance I like to mention the output resistance of the opamp. Normally, this parameter is always neglected during calaculation (set to zero). However, the Sallen-Key lowpass structure has one severe drawback: For rising frequencies there is a "direct" path between input and opamp output via the feedback capacitor. As a result the damping properties far above the cut-off frequency are heavily disturbed. This is due to a voltage drop across the finite output resistance of the opamp caused by the current that directly goes to the output node.

Answer (score 2):

*[This answer is somewhat off.  This is an answer to a different question other than the one that was asked.  See [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/189148/effects-of-filter-topology-on-transfer-function#comment391319_189149) below and [this answer in a different thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/189152/7036).]*

The transfer function will change with topology.

> Here is an image showing the gain of a discrete-time Butterworth
>   filter next to other common filter types. All of these filters are
>   fifth-order.
>   [image]
>   ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter#Comparison_with_other_linear_filters) of plots)

Another somewhat similar picture is Fig.5 (and discussion directly under it) in [Maxim tutorial 928](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/928).

Comment: This is not what I'd mean if I asked about topology. To me, "topology" means something like the difference between a Sallen-Key filter and a biquad filter. You could implement a Butterworth filter (or Chebyshev or whatever) with either one, you've only changed the arrangement of components to achieve the desired transfer function.

Comment: @ThePhoton  You are right.  I have added an apology to my answer.